# SQL 60,000 registros en menos de 3 minutos

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

El día de hoy tengo una pregunta de optimización, mi jefe quiere que guarde 60,000 registros en el menor tiempo posible. Para esto he hecho un query que toma información de un archivo **.csv** y la meto en una base temporal, de la cual hago un pequeño filtro y lleno mi **tabla destino**, pero procesar los 60 me toma aprox 8 min. Quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme a optimizar mi query o me propone una forma más rápida de almacenamiento. Estoy usando sql managment 2017.

```js
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stats_ddl') is not null DROP TABLE# stats_ddl

GO
CREATE TABLE# stats_ddl(
  [Cuenta] varchar(max), [Fecha] varchar(50), --[Hora] varchar(50), [Suc] varchar(50), [Descripcio] varchar(max), [Cargo / Abono] varchar(50), [Importe] varchar(50), [Saldo] varchar(50), [Referencia] varchar(50), [Concepto / Referencia Interbancaria] varchar(max) --
);
Go

declare @cargo varchar(max) = '',
  @count int = 0,
  @abono varchar(max) = ''

bulk insert erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl
from 'C:\mipc\some\where\myfile \thisismyfile.csv'
with(firstrow = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

  --select * from# stats_ddl

declare

@countb int = 1
set @count = (select count( * ) from# stats_ddl)
while @countb <= @count
begin
DECLARE @fechaMov VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) fecha FROM# stats_ddl),
  @Importe VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP(1)[Importe] FROM# stats_ddl),
  @simb VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP(1)[Cargo / Abono] FROM# stats_ddl),
  @saldo varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) saldo FROM# stats_ddl),
  @conceptoBanco varchar(max) = (SELECT TOP(1) saldo FROM# stats_ddl), @hh varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) Hora from# stats_ddl), @hhx varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) substring(Hora, 1, 2) as hhx from# stats_ddl), @hhy varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) substring(Hora, 3, 4) as hhy from# stats_ddl);

 
Set @fechaMov = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50), @fechaMov, 103), ':', '');
IF @simb LIKE '%+%'
BEGIN
SET @abono = @Importe
END
IF @simb LIKE '%-%'
BEGIN
SET @cargo = @Importe
END

INSERT INTO[dbo].[conciliacionesExcel]
  ([cuenta], [fechaMov], [cargo], [abono], [saldo], [conceptoBanco])
VALUES
  ('3', @fechaMov, @cargo, @abono, @saldo, @conceptoBanco)


  --PRINT 'fecha' + @fechaMov + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @count) + ' importe: ' + @Importe;
--print 'importes -- cargo: ' + @cargo + ' ' + 'abono ' + @abono;
--print 'saldo: ' + @saldo + ' ';
DELETE TOP(1) FROM# stats_ddl
  --SELECT @count = COUNT( * ) FROM# stats_ddl;
end

--select * from stats_ddl
```

Comment: Lo que podria recomendar es dejar de usar esos tipos de archivos, desconozco de donde se obtiene la información pero debe de venir de algun otro sistema, lo correcto es que si requieres de esa información la consultes desde su origen.

Comment: ese el tipo de archivo de origen

Comment: Me refiero a que esa información se obtiene de algun sistema y me imagino que lo que hacen es ir a ese sistemas y exportarla en un CSV y es lo que te pasan, esas son malas practicas muiy comunes en muchas empresas.

Comment: Si. cambia todo tu while por un insert into con su correpondiente where.. estas tratando de a 1 registro por vez, en lugar de dejar que la base de datos trate a todos juntos

Comment: @M.Gress mi querido paisano como sabes , el mundo empresarial de mx está plagado de malas practicas o practicas precarias, no tengo opción con el .csv

Comment: @gbianchi podrías postear una respuesta con lo que sugieres?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim Precisamente por eso debemos de tratar de erradicar esas malas practicas.

Comment: si. podrias aclarar cuales son los filtros que necesitas sobre tu tabla?

Comment: @gbianchi El único en verdad relevante es este  Set (arroba)fechaMov = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50), (arroba)fechaMov, 103), ':', '');

Comment: Pero eso no es un filtro. Ahi solamente estas haciendo un replace en la cadena. No hay un where en algun lado?

Comment: @gbianchi nop solo me interesa moverlo de la tabla temporal a la real, pero no hay ningún tipo de relación o condicional

Comment: felicitaciones bro, ahora sí tu pregunta está muy bien elaborada :) ¡Suerte con la solución!

Comment: Es por el while, lo que debes utilizar es BulkInsert ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 )

Comment: @Carlos podrías postear un ejemplo por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tengo una manera de probar pero creo que lo que buscas hacer es esto, prueba y me comentas si te funciono, simplemente se realiza un INSERT con un SELECT, donde se esta realizando el filtro de cargo y abono:

```
bulk insert erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl
from 'C:\mipc\some\where\myfile \thisismyfile.csv'
with(firstrow = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[conciliacionesExcel] ([cuenta], [fechaMov], [abono], [saldo], [conceptoBanco])
SELECT '3', [Fecha], [Importe], [Saldo], 'CONCEPTO' FROM erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl 
WHERE [Cargo / Abono] LIKE '%+%';

INSERT INTO [dbo].[conciliacionesExcel] ([cuenta], [fechaMov], [cargo], [saldo], [conceptoBanco])
SELECT '3', [Fecha], [Importe], [Saldo], 'CONCEPTO' FROM erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl 
WHERE [Cargo / Abono] LIKE '%-%';
```

Comment: similar a lo que se plantea arriba, pero no ... me devuelve:
>  (54469 rows affected) -- las del #stats_ddl
> (0 rows affected) -- conciliaiconesexcel

Comment: Revisa que trae el select, pero de que debe insertar algo debe jaja seguro puede ser que no estoy referenciando bien a que Tabla llamar es cuestión de que lo revises.

Answer (score 2):

Proba cambiando todo ese while por un:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[conciliacionesExcel]
SELECT '3', @fechaMov, @cargo, @abono, @saldo, @conceptoBanco
FROM erpsamfinanzas.dbo.#stats_ddl
```

Donde los @campo los tenes que reemplazar por los nombres de los campos de la tabla temporal que queres mandar.

Esto lo que va a hace es copiar toda tu tabla temporal a tu tabla conciliacionesExcel. tene en cuenta, que podrias tambien hacer el bulk insert directamente en esta tabla. y si despues necesitas hacer cambios, hacerlos sobre ella....

Comment: solo me genera un registro el primero de la tabla temporal

Comment: podrías especificar un poco la implementación?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim a que te referis? si ejecutas este query directamente en tu db despues del bulkinsert deberia funcionar...

Comment: @gbianchi correcto.!